# Stash and Cartthrob product options = Not added to cart

Tags: cartthrob, stash

I've hit a wall with this one. I using Stash and template partials to set my page. Currently I am NOT caching anything.

I have products that have product options associated with them and I have tried several approaches to try at get this to work. The bottom line is, that if I have the Carthtrob {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}"} tag on the page, the product fails to add to the cart.

I have tried to use this as a standalone and use Stash to pass an entry ID, I've also tried to set it as a stash item {stash:product_opt}code-here{/stash:product_opt}.

Stash is parsing the tags and outputting them. I am presuming it is a delightful parse order issue! Another thing I have tried is to embed it and also use it as a snippet. No cigar sadly.

Has anyone come across this?

`{exp:stash:set_list name="{segment_1}-Product" parse_tags="yes" scope="site" save="no" replace="no" refresh="1440"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" status="open" url_title="{last_segment}"}`

```
{stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}

{stash:e_id}{entry_id}{/stash:e_id}

{stash:product_options}
{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}" parse="inward"}
{if dynamic}
<dt>{option_label}</dt>
    <dd class="productOption">{input}</dd>
{if:else}

{if configuration} config{/if}
{if options_exist}
    {if configuration_label}{if:else} <dt>{option_label}</dt>{/if}
    <dd class="productOption">
        {select}
        <option {selected} value="{option_value}">
            {option_name}{if option_price_numeric > 0} +{option_price}{/if}
        </option>
        {/select}
    </dd>
    {/if}
{/if}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
{/stash:product_options}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding parse_depth="2" to your set_list tag? You have some nested module tag pairs there.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Yea, I have tried that. If the tag is parsing before Stash works with it, can you think of any other reason why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I've completed something similar but we captured all entries to a to a series of big stash lists then used `get_list name="{segment_1}-Product" match="#{last_segment}#" against="urltitle"}` to pull in the relevant item or series of items.

This is the base theory we used, **you'll have to experiment** to get it to work in your scenario...

```
//Just capture the elements you require, leave styling to later…
//Set depth to 2, we're parsing exp:channel + also getting nested info from item:options
{exp:stash:set_list name="{segment_1}-Product" parse_tags="yes" scope="site" parse_depth="2"save="no" replace="no" refresh="1440"} {exp:channel:entries channel="products" status="open" url_title="{last_segment}"}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:urltitle}{url_title}{/stash:urltitle}
    {stash:e_id}{entry_id}{/stash:e_id}
    //Capture the options as a nested list
    {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="product_options{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes" scope="site"}
        {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}" parse="inward"}
            {stash:optionlabel}{option_label}{/stash:optionlabel}
            {stash:optionname}{option_name}{/stash:optionname}
            {stash:optionvalue}{option_value}{/stash:optionvalue}
            {stash:optionprice}{option_price}{/stash:optionprice}
        {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
    {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

//Grab the list and format it however you choose…
{exp:stash:get_list name="{segment_1}-Product" scope="site"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{e_id}</p>
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="product_options{entry_id}" scope="site"}
    Label: {option_label}
    Name: {optionname}  Value: {optionvalue} Price: {optionprice}<br>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks stuartmcd69. I shall give that a go. Looks promising.